# The shortest path is not shown correctly at the time box

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, shortest-path

I am trying to find the shortest path using "Road Graph Plugin" in QGIS 2.18.22. When I set the Criterion as "Length", the length is shown but the time is not shown and it is shown as "infh". What does the "infh" mean? How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: What settings do you use? Have a look at https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_road_graph.html

Comment: You should really upgrade to qgis 3 - 2.18 is long unsupported